# Scope of returned resource highly depandant on user role encoded in JWT token - is it RESTful?

Tags: python, django

I'm working on API that tries to stay in RESTful principles, although one requirement keeps bugging me.

We use JWT based authentication. Inside JWT claims we store roles of the user. Now our main GET endpoint (let's call it ListAllOffers for simplicity) behaves differently depending on what role the user have:

- if API recognizes admin via JWT it responds with full list of Offers
- if API recognizes ordinary user via JWT it responds with narrowed list of Offers (depending on relation in DB)

My concerns is: **is it ok according to REST principles or any unwritten REST practices?** I am used to modify response object according to argument from url, params from querystring or alternatively via header values. Altering JSON response basing JWT seems not explicit enough that is feels some kinda strange.

---

Bonus question: is it against any of REST principles how should this requirement be implemented.

Answer (score 1):

You'll find lots of APIs have resources where the value changes depending on the authenticated user (see [GitHub's API](https://developer.github.com/v3/users/#get-the-authenticated-user)).

When it comes to REST the endpoint must always reference the same resource. However, you may choose to represent that resource in any way you wish. Masking some of the offers because the user is not an admin has not changed the resource **only the representation you are giving to that user**.

While the [REST specification](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) doesn't have any specific examples of changing representations due to authorisation it is still a worthwhile read.

If you are concerned about changing the representation implicitly there are a few options available that would make it more explicit whilst still following RESTful standards.

You could add a query parameter that explicitly requests only the current user's offers: `/offers?show=mine`.

If the offers are 'owner' by a user you could also do something like: `/users/{username}/offers`. Here a user would be authorised only for their own offers. An admin would of course be authorised for any.

Overall the key point is this: an endpoint must always represent the same resource but how it represents it is up to you.